# How to filter dataframe on two columns and output cumulative sum

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I am early beginner.

I have the following dataframe (df1) with transaction dates as index, columns = account #, quantity of transaction, and ticker.

```
             Account  Quantity Symbol/CUSIP
Trade Date                                 
2020-03-31         1       NaN    990156937
2020-03-31         2     0.020        IIAXX
2020-03-24         1       NaN    990156937
2020-03-20         1   650.000          DOC
2020-03-23         1       NaN    990156937
...              ...       ...          ...
2017-11-24         2    55.000          QQQ
2018-01-01         1    10.000         AMZN
2018-01-01         1   250.000          HOS
2017-09-13         1   229.051        VFINX
2017-09-21         1     1.118        VFINX
[266 rows x 3 columns]
```

I would like to populate a 2nd dataframe (df2) which shows the total quantity on every day between the min & max of the index of (df1), grouped by account and by ticker. Below is am empty dataframe of what I am looking to do:

```
df2 = Total Quantity by ticker and account #, on every single day between min and max of df1

              990156937 IIAXX  DOC  AER  NaN ATVI    H VCSH GOOGL  VOO   VG  \
2020-03-31 3       NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN   
           2       NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN   
           1       NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN   
2020-03-30 3       NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN   
           2       NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN   
           1       NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN   
2020-03-29 3       NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN   
           2       NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN   
           1       NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN
```

Thus, for each day between the min of max of the transaction dates in df1 - I need to calculate the cumulative sum of all transaction of that date or earlier, grouped by account and ticker.

How could I accomplish this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# first I reproduce a similar dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({"date": pd.date_range("2017-1-1", periods=3).repeat(6),
                   "account": [1, 1, 3, 1, 2, 3, 2,2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 2,2,1],
                   "quantity": [123, 0.020, np.NaN, 650, 345, np.NaN, 345, 456, 121, 243, 445, 453, 987, np.NaN, 76, 143, 87, 19],
                   "symbol": ['990156937', '990156937', '990156937', 'DOC', 'AER', 'ATVI', 'AER', 'ATVI', 'IIAXX',
                              '990156937', '990156937', '990156937', 'DOC', 'AER', 'ATVI', 'AER', 'ATVI', 'IIAXX']})
```

This is what it looks like:

```
       date  account  quantity     symbol
0 2017-01-01        1    123.00  990156937
1 2017-01-01        1      0.02  990156937
2 2017-01-01        3       NaN  990156937
3 2017-01-01        1    650.00        DOC
4 2017-01-01        2    345.00        AER
```

You want to go to a wide format using `unstack`:

```
# You groupby date, account and symbol and sum the quantities
df = df.groupby(["date", "account", "symbol"]).agg({"quantity":"sum"})
df_wide = df.unstack()
# Finally groupby account to get the cumulative sum per account across dates
# Fill na with 0 to get cumulative sum right
df_wide = df_wide.fillna(0)
df_wide = df_wide.groupby(df_wide.index.get_level_values("account")).cumsum()
```

You get the result:

```
                  quantity                            
                   990156937    AER   ATVI    DOC  IIAXX
date       account                                      
2017-01-01 1          123.02    0.0    0.0  650.0    0.0
           2            0.00  345.0    0.0    0.0    0.0
           3            0.00    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0
2017-01-02 1          366.02    0.0    0.0  650.0  121.0
           2          445.00  690.0  456.0    0.0    0.0
```

Comment: I was looking to get the cumulative quantity on every day between the min and max of the initial df (not just on the transaction dates). For example, in your result, DOC should be 650.0 on 2017-01-03 as well, and there should be row for account 2 on 2017-01-01. 

I was looking for cumulative quantity for every symbol, for every account, on every day.

Comment: @andrewmarco I modified the answer by adding a fillna with 0 so that the cumulative sum works according to what you wanted. There was no row for account 2 on the first date because my example dataframe did not have observations for this but I added some and now the account 2 does appear for that date. Does it correspond to your desired output ?